# How to log CPU % usage of all processes with timestamps for Windows?

Tags: windows, cpu-usage

How can I log all activity of my CPU usage of all my processes?
**I need text output for example csv: Timestamp, Process name, CPU % usage**
I can't find any solutions that meet my requirement.

I used to "Perfomance Monitor" (aka Perfomance Counters > \Process(*)%Processor Time), but it doesn't show me the information I need. Moreover, the outcome is not clear at all.
For example,
[image]
So, I need to convert this data to readable format which is not easy.
The same data, but csv output:
[image]
Obfuscated data is the name of my work device and the name of the process are in the same field, and again, there are big numbers that need to be converted to a readable format (% of CPU).
This format needs to be further parsed and restuctured to make it possible to create some graphs (at most, you can make graphs per process).

I tried some tools from Sysinternals like Process Monitor, Process Explorer. I found how to convert "% Processor Time" to readable "% of CPU usage", but I can't say that it shows correct numbers. I can see historical data of CPU usage by Process Monitor via GUI, but it's not a comfortable way to monitor CPU usage. I didn't find any normal solutions.

Comment: What research have you done, what solutions have you tried?

Comment: Hi @music2myear!
I tried some tools from Sysinternals like Process Monitor, Process Explorer. I found how to convert "% Processor Time" to readable "% of CPU usage", but I can't say that it shows correct numbers. I can see historical data of CPU usage by Process Monitor via GUI, but it's not a comfortable way to monitor CPU usage. I didn't find any normal solutions.

Comment: That info needs to be in the body of the question. Please use the edit button to improve your question. A better question is more likely to get good answers and we really encourage using that edit button for this purpose.

Comment: Hi @music2myear Done.